# Fazer formas com CSS

Tags: css, css3

Preciso fazer essa forma com CSS. Mas não pode ser com ***border***.

Segue a forma: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não pode ser com borda pelo motivo de que formas usando border não me permitem posicionar textos dentro delas.

Comment: Não pode ser com borda por que não consigo posicionar texto dentro dela se for feita com borda. É para trabalho prático.

Comment: Como pode ver @danilo, são formas diferentes, então não tem como ser duplicata.

Comment: Usa uma imagem com o background dessa forma, então, uê, já que o css não antende ;)

Comment: @TiagoP.C segue a mesma ideia, não deixa de ser forma geometrica, basta um pouco mais de esforço

Comment: Não, pois lá a maioria foi feita com border.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters estou tentando evitar usar imagens, pois isso pesa mais que CSS. Então insisto em tentar usar CSS, caso não encontre alguma maneira de fazer isso com css, usarei imagem.

Comment: O problema é isso também funcionar em todos os browsers, né. Já tentou SVG (ou também acha pesado)? Você poderia usar duas divs, não? uma com o border por baixo e outra por cima com o texto

Comment: O problema é a questão de responsividade, usando mais de uma div, ficará difícil de se adaptar em diversas resoluções. Teria que ser algo puramente CSS de uma div. Caso contrário acho que fica melhor usar imagem.

Comment: Da uma olhada nisso aqui. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/?redirect_from_locale=pt

Comment: Muito boa referência, @PauloHDSousa! Obrigado, amigo! ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta uma linha apenas de CSS, usando  *gradient* em vez de cor sólida:

```
background: linear-gradient(170deg, #ffffff 0%,#fff 49.8%,#000 50.2%,#000 100%);
```

Segue um exemplo bem simples, já com prefixo para vários navegadores:

```css
#elemento {
  background: #ffffff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-13deg, #fff 0%, #fff 49.8%, #000 50.2%, #000 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-13deg, #fff 0%,#fff 49.8%,#000 50.2%,#000 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(167deg, #ffffff 0%,#fff 49.8%,#000 50.2%,#000 100%);

  width:400px;
  height:180px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align:center;
  color:#ccc;
  font-size:80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="elemento">TEXTO<br>TEXTO</div>
```

Pus as versões prefixadas mais para mostrar a diferença de sintaxe na parte do ângulo, mas as versões modernas dos browsers trabalham bem sem os prefixos.

Deixei um mínimo "vão" de 0.4 no encontro do centro para melhorar a interpolação. Vale dizer que os *browsers* que são baseados em Chromium tem uma implementação precária que leva a fazer um pouco de serrilhamento, isso é problema de programação do *browser* e não na técnica utilizada. Tanto que no IE11, por exemplo, fica perfeito.

Comment: esta é ainda uma melhor solução! +1

Comment: @Chun eu até gostei da engenhosidade da sua, mas achei relevante colocar o gradient, pois muita gente nao sabe que dá pra fazer "gradient sem gradient", se colar 2 cores sólidas uma na outra. Depois edito a resposta explicando melhor.

Comment: Muito boa resposta, realmente não sabia que dava pra fazer isso, acho que muito pouca gente sabia, obrigado pela resposta!! +1

Answer (score 3):

Podes fazer isso da seguinte maneira, utilizando a propriedade [`transform: rotate();`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp):

```css
.container {
    height: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.shape {
    background: #000;
    height: 150px;
    width: 112%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
    left: -8px;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.reshape {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="shape">
    <div class="reshape">texto aqui</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Se quiseres rodar apenas o texto para a posição inicial:

```css
.container {
    height: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.shape {
    background: #000;
    height: 150px;
    width: 112%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
    left: -8px;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
.reshape {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="shape">
    <div class="reshape">texto aqui</div>
  </div>
</div>
```